# Saving camera pics in a folder other than gallery

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to launch the camera and take a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430527/how-to-launch-the-camera-and-take-a-picture)

I am trying to save images that my app captured using the camera in a location other than gallery. I am new to Android; how do I specify the path?

Answer (score 1):

Simple tutorial for saving the Camera Picture in other folder : [Simple Photo Capture](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/)

Or You can refer to the answers given here previously on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430527/how-to-launch-the-camera-and-take-a-pic)